# ARM template - multiple joindomain extensions

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to deploy 2 VM's (or more later on.. ) that then need to join the domain.. but the arm template doesnt want to work..

The VM's themselves deploy fine, but when it comes to the domain join extension. the line
"name": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), padLeft(copyIndex(0),2, '0'), '/JoinDomain')]",

doesnt seem to work in this case.. I also tried to run some other options on this, but no luck as of yet..

any idea how to make this work?

```
      "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "name": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), copyindex())]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": 2
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), copyindex(), '-nic'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('SqlVMSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), copyindex())]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[parameters('windowsImagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[parameters('windowsImageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('windowsImageSKU')]",
            "version": "[parameters('windowsImageVersion')]"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), copyindex(), '_OSDisk')]",
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage",
            "managedDisk": {
              "storageAccountType": "[parameters('diskType')]"
            }
          },
          "dataDisks": [
            {
              "lun": 0,
              "name": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), copyindex(), '_datadisk1')]",
              "createOption": "Empty",
              "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sqlDiskSize')]",
              "caching": "None",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "[parameters('diskType')]"
              }
            },
            {
              "lun": 1,
              "name": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), copyindex(), '_logdisk1')]",
              "createOption": "Empty",
              "diskSizeGB": "[variables('sqlDiskSize')]",
              "caching": "None",
              "managedDisk": {
                "storageAccountType": "[parameters('diskType')]"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces',concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), copyindex(), '-nic'))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
{
        "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "name": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix'), padLeft(copyIndex(0),2, '0'), '/JoinDomain')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "copy": {
            "name": "DomainJoinLoop",
            "count": "2"
            },
        "dependsOn": [ "virtualMachineLoop" ],
        "properties": 
            {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
            "type": "JsonADDomainExtension",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "settings":
                {
                "Name": "[parameters('domainName')]",
                "User": "[concat(parameters('domainName'), '\\', parameters('adminUsername'))]",
                "OUPath": "[parameters('ouPath')]",
                "Restart": "true",
                "Options": "3"
                },
            "protectedsettings": {"Password": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"}
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the name of the extension needs to match the parent vm's name...  you don't have the `pad()` function in the vm name.  So either need to add it there or change the extension name, e.g.

```json
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
"name": "[concat(variables('sqlNamePrefix', copyIndex(), '/JoinDomain')]",
```

Note, some extension types don't allow more than one per VM, IDK if the JsonADDomainExtension allows that but it will tell you if it doesn't once the name is fixed.